# How to create Parent record on Child record creation and assign Parent ID to Child record in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables - [**stakeholders**] and [**organizations**].

**FK** from [**organizations.stakeholder_id**] to [**stakeholders.id**].

I want to create [**stakeholder**] record automatically when new [**organization**] is created AND to assign newly created [**stakeholder.id**] back to [**organizations.stakeholder_id**] in the same transaction.

Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible to create a child record without creating the parent record, but you can always(even in programming languages) insert into the parent table first and then insert into the child table.

```
insert into parent_table(id) values(1);
insert into child_table(childid,name,id) values(1,"x",1);
```

For example in any programming language if you have the id number that you want to add to your database you can use it in both insert statements.

Comment: I got idea to try use MySQL Triggers and Stored Procedures. I can call some Trigger on INSERT [organizations].